# Countifs with more than 2 "or" statements

Tags: excel

The following formula works as intended:

```
SUM(COUNTIFS(Data!$O:$O,">="&Leaderboard!I$202,Data!$O:$O,"<"&Leaderboard!J$202,Data!$DH:$DH,Leaderboard!$B203,Data!$HG:$HG,{"<>-","-","<>-"},Data!$HD:$HD,{"Q4 2018 Campaign","Q4 2018 Campaign",""}))
```

However, I read that having more than two "or" array statements inside the `countifs()` statement, will cause the wrong results, ie. I shouldn't do this:

```
SUM(COUNTIFS(Data!$O:$O,">="&Leaderboard!I$202,Data!$O:$O,"<"&Leaderboard!J$202,Data!$DH:$DH,Leaderboard!$B203,Data!$HG:$HG,{"<>-","-","<>-"},Data!$HD:$HD,{"Q4 2018 Campaign","Q4 2018 Campaign",""},Data!$HE:$HE,{"";">Data!$HF:$HF"}))
```

Can you show how I can re-write this formula so it works?

Currently the best I can come up with is:

```
SUM(COUNTIFS(Data!$O:$O,">="&Leaderboard!I$202,Data!$O:$O,"<"&Leaderboard!J$202,Data!$DH:$DH,Leaderboard!$B203,Data!$HG:$HG,{"<>-","-","<>-"},Data!$HD:$HD,{"Q4 2018 Campaign","Q4 2018 Campaign",""},Data!$HE:$HE,""))
+
SUM(COUNTIFS(Data!$O:$O,">="&Leaderboard!I$202,Data!$O:$O,"<"&Leaderboard!J$202,Data!$DH:$DH,Leaderboard!$B203,Data!$HG:$HG,{"<>-","-","<>-"},Data!$HD:$HD,{"Q4 2018 Campaign","Q4 2018 Campaign",""},Data!$HE:$HE,">"&"Data!$HF:$HF))
```

Comment: or(a,b,c) == or(a, or(b,c))

Comment: You say that your first formula "works as intended", so I take it that you are aware that that formula does NOT give the total number of rows within the Data sheet for which: (1) the entry in column O is greater than or equal to that in Leaderboard!I202 and less than that in Leaderboard!J202; (2) the entry in column DH is equal to that in Leaderboard!B203; (3) the entry in column HG is either "<>-", "-" or "<>-"; (4) the entry in column HD is either "Q4 2018 Campaign", "Q4 2018 Campaign" or ""?

Comment: Rather it gives the total number of rows within the Data sheet for which: (1) the entry in column O is greater than or equal to that in Leaderboard!I202 and less than that in Leaderboard!J202; (2) the entry in column DH is equal to that in Leaderboard!B203; (3) EITHER (3.1) the entry in column HG is "<>-" AND the entry in column HD is "Q4 2018 Campaign" OR (3.2) the entry in column HG is "-" AND the entry in column HD is "Q4 2018 Campaign" OR (3.3) the entry in column HG is "<>-" AND the entry in column HD is "".

Comment: @XORLX yes, it is option #2 (I know I need to put a ";" if I wanted #1). I was just wondering how I can write it as one function, rather than summing 2

Comment: Ok, just wanted confirmation. But the final formula you posted is flawed, in that the final criterion, i.e. Data!$HD:$HD, will resolve to just a single value. Are you trying to count the number of rows for which the entry in column HE is EITHER blank OR greater than the corresponding entry in column HD?

Comment: That's correct! Can you also please clarify why the solution in "Currently the best I can come up with is:" is not what I am trying to do? As far as I understand I am only adding an "AND" statement to two correct countifs functions and summing

Comment: So column HD contains numerics, as well as text entries such as "Q4 2018 Campaign"? Or are you wanting a greater than comparison based on text also?

Comment: Re your question, you cannot perform row-by-row comparisons within COUNTIF(S), etc, so your second construction is faulty. It could work by pure chance, since all entries in column HE will be evaluated as to whether they are greater than a SINGLE CELL within column HD (the precise location of this cell will depend upon in which row your formula lies).

Comment: @XORLX apologies, `Data!$HE:$HE,">"&"Data!$HD:$HD` was a typo- HD was supposed to be HF, I corrected. HD is campaign name or blank, HE is campaign date or blank, HF is call date or blank, HQ is company name or "-"

Comment: Im in big trouble if you cant evaluate HE vs HF- my entire sheet has that assumption LOL. I am basically just trying to compare two date columns, both in the same row in "Data" tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to switch to `SUMPRODUCT`, though as such I strongly advise against the use of entire column references.

`=SUMPRODUCT((Data!O1:O100>=Leaderboard!I202)*(Data!O1:O100<Leaderboard!J202)*(Data!DH1:DH100=Leaderboard!B203)*((Data!HE1:HE100>Data!HF1:HF100)+(Data!HE1:HE100="")>0)*(Data!HG1:HG100={"<>-","-","<>-"})*(Data!HD1:HD100={"Q4 2018 Campaign","Q4 2018 Campaign",""}))`

I have removed all absolute referencing (insert as desired) and chosen an upper row reference of 100 (amend as required).

Regards

Comment: This is awesome thank you. So you think you will be able to brake it down into parts for me? So I can replicate it across the other 300 fields, with varying logic..

Comment: Seems to be missing a few variables from original by the way like, and some incomplete references like `Data!O1:O100Data!HF1:HF100`

Comment: Hmm. Appears that several asterisks have been removed from that solution. Not sure how to ensure they appear. Will look into it.

Comment: Ok. Successful!

Comment: Question, aren't you still doing row-by-row comparison while using non-absolute referencing? example: `(Data!HE1:HE100>Data!HF1:HF100)`

Comment: Yes, but I'm not using COUNTIFS! SUMPRODUCT can handle row-by-row comparisons.

Comment: ARGH. Thank you!!

Comment: It looks like if I select a non entire column reference, unless the upper row is within the possible range- I get a #N/A error. My data source is dynamic so I can't go into it and change it continuously, hence the absolute reference. What is the risk of using them? is there an alternative?

Comment: Are you talking about absolute references here or entire column references? Apologies if my removing the former in the formula I posted confused you. As I said, put them back in as desired; it won't affect anything.

Comment: Yeah I put them back. I actually realized I have a problem with the function.. posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52785950/why-do-i-get-a-different-result-for-two-formulas-that-are-supposed-to-be-the-sam

Comment: Apologies. I see where the double-counting could occur. Have amended the formula.

Comment: Can you explain what was changed, and why it caused duplication?

Comment: I hadn't considered that the two clauses either side of the plus sign in the part `(Data!HE1:HE100>Data!HF1:HF100)+(Data!HE1:HE100="")` might not be mutually exclusive (they aren't: a null string in column HE will be considered by Excel to be greater than a (numeric) date in column HF). As such, the above construction would result in a value of 2 for any rows where the entry in HE is blank, thus over-counting.

Comment: Got it. @XORLX RE: entire column references, my data is connected to a database, so number of rows keeps changing. If I specify a range larger than that of the data, I get a #N/A error. Hence the entire column references

Comment: I don't understand. An entire column reference is also a range larger than that of the data. Just a single version of the formula I posted, if amended to include entire column references, would be forced to calculate more than 7 million cells, an astonishing amount for a single formula.

Comment: I am not sure why- but I get a #VALUE error, instead of a result returned, unless I use absolute references

Comment: Ah. You appear to be again confusing absolute references with entire column references. Use whatever absolute/relative referencing you require; that is not the issue. The issue is referencing entire columns, e.g. Data!O:O, etc., instead of e.g. Data!O1:O100. The latter calculates over 100 cells; the former over more than 1 million, irrespective of the number of non-blank cells within that column. This is not the case with COUNTIF(S), SUMIF(S), etc., for which, for technical reasons, you can 'get away' with referencing entire columns with no detriment to performance.

Comment: Apologies if I am not being clear, changing from Data!O:O, to Data!O2:O10000 returns a #VALUE error for countifs and a #NA error for sumproduct.

Comment: And you changed all other references to the Data sheet similarly? Those errors would indicate that you have some column references of differing dimensions (i.e. lengths) within the formulas.

Comment: Ah you are right, I just retried and it works, must have missed one reference before. Also, apparently `+(Data!HE1:HE100="")>0` is not needed all together since `null>Data!HF1:HF100` (where HF contains dates) resolves to `TRUE`